# Maven: Dependency on JAR within external ZIP

Tags: java, maven

I have a Java + Maven project that depends on an external JAR, which is

- not in any repository, but
- inside a ZIP file
- downloadable at a public URL

I could of course create a POM and upload the extracted JAR to my private repository, but I would like to have my project ready for users with no access to my repository.
So I am trying to find a way to define a dependency inside my pom.xml, which downloads the ZIP, extracts the JAR and adds it to the classpath (and later adds it to a packaged application).

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Before trying to solve this complex task, I would make sure that there isn't any maven repository on the internet that hosts the desired jar.

Comment: Sure. The JARs in question are from this site: http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html
I searched at mvnrepository.com